# Ansible - RabbitMQ - Showing error even after installing pika package

Tags: ansible, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I'm a newbie to `ansible` and `RabbitMQ`. I'm just starting off with `Hello World`. Below is my playbook for reading and retrieving messages to `RabbitMQ`.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name: "something"
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.7

  tasks:
  - name: Publish a message to a queue with headers
    vars:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.7
    rabbitmq_publish:
      url: "amqps://xx@roedeer.rmq.cloudamqp.com/xx"
      queue: 'RunningQueue'
      body: "Hello world from ansible module rabbitmq_publish"
      durable: yes
      content_type: "text/plain"

  - name: Get 2 messages off a queue and set a fact for re-use
    debug:
      messages: "{{ lookup('rabbitmq', url='amqps://xx@roedeer.rmq.cloudamqp.com/xx', queue='JobQueue') }}"
```

After I execute the above playbook. The message is saving in the queue, but when i retrieve the message i'm getting below error.

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'rabbitmq'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: pika python package is required for rabbitmq lookup."}`

`pika` python package is already installed on the localhost. Proof is that it is able to produce message to queue. But I'm facing error when trying to consume it. Can anyone help me with this? Google will tell me install `pika` on host, but i have already done that.

```
ansible-playbook 2.8.12
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['**', '**']
  ansible python module location = **
  executable location = /usr/local/opt/ansible@2.8/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.9 (default, Sep  9 2020, 00:09:13) [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add an output of `ansible-playbook -v`? Although your are targeting localhost, there is still a separation between controller and target, and lookups are always running on controller. I suspect you installed the package in python 3.7 interpreter as declared for the target in your playbook but that the controller is using an other python version.

Comment: Actually, even i thought the same and downgraded from 2.9 to 2.8. Now i have Python3.7 at runtime. But its throwing the same error

Comment: I don't know how you installed ansible but the path does not look like a default one I know. Are you sure it is not using some other installed interpreter than /usr/local/bin/python3.7 ? I would bet a case a champagne that it is the case...

Comment: i used brew install .. maybe that's the reason. Let me check with pip to make sure if I get the same error

Comment: I guess, I owe you a champagne.  Lesson learnt, brew should not be used for ansible(non-native apps in general)